# I have a problem of login

Tags: login-screen

I have made a recover of deleted files with a software which was stopped and after that I can't login. When I write my password and enter the login display is appearing again. How could I resolve this problem? I don't want to reinstall having afraid of loosing my other files.

Comment: What OS & release, have you tried logging in via *text* terminal?  It's likely you've filled $HOME and thus your GUI sesssions can't create needed workfiles & login is rejected (ie. login-loop), but it's not the only issue that can cause that...

Comment: Did you delete your files by putting them into the Trash? Or did you delete your files in the shell using `rm`? Or did you delete your files some other way?  How you recover your files depends upon how you deleted them, and some recovery methods do not require you to login.